# How to insert a Table within a Loop - Getting Run-Time Error '1004'

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on creating a Loop through all worksheets, except the first Tab - `Sheet1 (TOC)`.

On every sheet, the Data will start in A3, and will go through Column L.

The first action needs to create a Table with the Data starting in A3 thru Column L.  However, I am getting the error code:

> `Run-time error '1004': The worksheet data for a table needs to be on the same sheet as the table.

What does this mean, and how can I fix it?

I currently have:

```
    Dim wb As ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim TableName As String
    Dim LstObj As ListObjects
    Dim LastRow As Long


For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        If .Name <> "Sheet1" Then

'Insert Table
    .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A3").CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = "TableName"

'Apply a filter to $ Share for all Brands (Largest to Smallest)
    .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("C3"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending
    .AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
    .ListObjects(TableName).ShowAutoFilterDropDown = False

        End If
    End With
Next ws
```

Comment: You need to add a period in front of your `Range` calls to make sure they refer to `ws`.

Comment: Thank you.  Now it's says a Table can't overlap another table.  But the data isn't in a table format..?

Comment: What does `Debug.Print .Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Address` return?

Comment: `$A$2:$B$6`  I just realized the If Then was wrong.. Instead of `=`, I changed it to `If .Name <> "Sheet1" Then`.   However, now it's skipping "Sheet1" , but not going to the next ws

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is unqualified `Range` calls:

```
Range("A3").CurrentRegion '<~ doesn't actually refer to ws
```

Without the preceding `.`, there's an implicit `ActiveSheet`, thus the worksheet data for the table is *not* on the same sheet, i.e. `ws`, as the table.

Fully qualify the `Range` calls:

```
.Range("A3").CurrentRegion
...
Key:=.Range("C3")
```